# Hide RzSplitter left pane based on condition in delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a TrzSplitter that has two panes, Pane1 and Pane2.
I am trying to hide Pane1 and maximaze the width of the Pane2.

I don't know how to access each left and right pane. What I am doing is I am hiding every control inside the left pane, and it works fine.

Is there any quicker and cleaner way of accessing the left pane itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access both panes of a *TRzSplitter* with its properties *UpperLeft* and *LowerRight*. To make the left pane invisible, just set `mySplitter.UpperLeft.Visible := False;` (assuming the *TRzSplitter* instance is named *mySplitter*).

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that you can get a similar effect by setting `mySplitter.Percent := 0`, as this allows you to set intermediate values.